# How can I retrieve the tag from the syslog logs that are sent to Logstash?

Tags: docker, logstash, syslog

I have set up my Docker daemon so that the logs of all my containers are forwarded to a Logstash application listening on port 5000, using the following configuration for `daemon.json` :

```
{
  "log-driver": "syslog",
  "log-opts": {
    "syslog-address": "udp://localhost:5000",
    "syslog-format": "rfc3164",
    "tag": "{{.Name}}"
  },

  "hosts": [
    "tcp://0.0.0.0:2375",
    "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
  ]
}
```

Since many different containers are creating logs at the same time, I would like to be able to filter the container names when I visualize their logs within my ELK stack. However, I'm not sure how I can retrieve, in Logstash, the "tag" that I have set as part of the "log-opts" in the Docker daemon configuration above.

What I tried is to simply retrieve it as a variable and forward it to a field in the Logstash configuration, but it just stores the text "%{tag}" as a string. Is it possible to retrieve the tag of the source container in the Logstash configuration?

logstash.conf :

```
input {
  udp {
    port => 5000
    type => syslog
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["elasticsearch"]
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    if [message] =~ "^<\d+>\s*\w+\s+\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+\s\S+\s\w+(\/\S+|)\[\d+\]:.*$" {
      grok {
        match => {
          "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:hostname} %{DATA:container_hash}(?:\[%{POSINT}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:real_message}"
        }
        remove_field => ["message"]
      }
      mutate {
        add_field => {
          "tag" => "%{tag}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit : If I don't remove the `message` field like I do in the logstash configuration, then the `message` field looks something like this when I view the logs in Kibana :

```
<30>May 15 15:13:23 devlocal e9713f013ebb[1284]: 192.168.56.110 - - [15/May/2019:15:13:23 +0200] "GET /server/status HTTP/1.0" 200 54 0.003 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.3.3 curl/7.64.0 PHP/7.2.17" "172.30.0.2"
```

So the `tag` that I'm looking for isn't part of the `message` ; hence I don't know from where I can retrieve it.

Comment: @baudsp Which JSON are you referring to? Doesn't syslog transfer log lines as plain strings?

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. Could you perhaps post one or two sample line from your logs?

Comment: Also when doing  `add_field => {"tag" => "%{tag}"}`, you add a new field, called tag, with the value of an already existing field, here tag; so if the field tag did not exist before, it will just put the `%{tag}` in it. You'd have to edit your grok pattern so that it retrieve the tag value.

Comment: @baudsp I edited the question with an example of log line as sent by syslog. As you can see the `tag` that I'm looking for isn't part of it

Comment: Your daemon process looks like it is adding the tag already - you shouldn't need to do this in your logstash pipeline. You can filter based on tag via a conditional e.g. `if "tagName" in [tags] `

Comment: @Adam Do you mean that when I look at the logs in Kibana for instance, I should be able to see the container name in the `tags` field? It is not the case : I do have a `tags` field but it's either an empty string or the string `_grokparsefailure`

Comment: Can you try changing your log-driver to `gelf`instead of `syslog`? https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/gelf/#examples

Comment: @Adam How do I retrieve the name of the origin container in logstash after that change? I still don't see it in Kibana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem could be related to the log-driver that you chose.
Changing the log-driver to `gelf` should give you access to tags, and a variety of other fields e.g. below

```
    {
  "_index": "logstash-2017.04.27",
  "_type": "docker",
  "_id": "AVuuiZbeYg9q2vv-JShe",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "source_host": "172.18.0.1",
    "level": 6,
    "created": "2017-04-27T08:24:45.69023959Z",
    "message": "My Message Thu Apr 27 08:31:44 UTC 2017",
    "type": "docker",
    "version": "1.1",
    "command": "/bin/sh -c while true; do echo My Message `date`; sleep 1; done;",
    "image_name": "alpine",
    "@timestamp": "2017-04-27T08:31:44.338Z",
    "container_name": "squarescaleweb_plop_1",
    "host": "plop-xps",
    "@version": "1",
    "tag": "staging",
    "image_id": "sha256:4a415e3663882fbc554ee830889c68a33b3585503892cc718a4698e91ef2a526",
    "container_id": "12b7bcd3f2f54e017680090d01330f542e629a4528f558323e33f7894ec6be53"
  },
  "fields": {
    "created": [
      1493281485690
    ],
    "@timestamp": [
      1493281904338
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1493281904338
  ]
}
```

> example from:
>   https://gist.github.com/eunomie/e7a183602b8734c47058d277700fdc2d

You would also need to send your logs via UDP instead of TCP.
You can change your daemon.json to read

```
{
  "log-driver": "syslog",
  "log-opts": {
    "gelf-address": "udp://localhost:<PORT>"
    "tag": "{{.Name}}"
  },

  "hosts": [
    "tcp://0.0.0.0:2375",
    "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
  ]
}
```

I'm not sure what port you have logstash configured to receive UDP packets, but for GELF it seems like 12201 is the default for logstash.

After the messages are sent into logstash, you can create a pipeline to extract the fields of your choice. e.g. `[container_name]`

Comment: Thanks! It took me a while to understand that syslog just doesn't know anything about what containers the log lines come from, but gelf does. Just a few remarks on your answer if you would like to edit it : 1) I was already sending logs via UDP (see my `daemon.json`), but I had to replace `gelf-address` with `syslog-address`. 2) The port that I configured for Logstash is shown in the `logstash.conf` config that I shared : it's port 5000.